# Conditional Launch Conditions

Tags: wix

Is it possible in Wix to have launch conditions that are only executed based on some other condition?  And ideally, I'd like to group all of my launch conditions together, and apply one conditional check to the entire group rather than each condition.

I've tried a number of things already, such as placing my launch conditions in a Fragment, and referencing the Fragment in the Product with a Condition, but nothing I try seems to make Wix happy.

My goal here is to bypass all of my installer's launch conditions if the correct property is set on the command line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Windows Installer does not support a "grouping" condition. You'd need to add the "bypass" property to each condition. Something like:

```
<Condition>Installed OR BYPASS_PROPERTY OR (Other_Conditions AND More_Conditions)</Condition>
```

Note: Added "Installed OR" there to ensure the product can always be uninstalled.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Thanks.

Comment: @Rob Mensching - can you pleas explain a bit more about the  "Installed OR"?